# How do I transition between these GUI frames?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

So, I have a Java program here and it's essentially a choose your own adventure game. At each step of the game, the user has a choice between two options, "one" or "two" and those options branch off into different parts of the story.

For example: You are a female college student named Angelina Jackson 
who is currently on a break from studying. 
You are just at your favorite neighborhood cafe one day, 
when you bump into a stranger and spill your coffee all over both of you! 
What do you do?
Option one: Immediately apologize for being so clumsy. 
Option two: You're furious because your shoes were brand new. 
You turn around and prepare to give him the scolding of his life!

Currently, the program runs as text in Eclipse. I'm trying to make the entire game appear on GUI as shown in the picture below. The problem is that I can't transition between the different frames of the project, as there are multiple frames like the one in the picture below.

How can I connect those frames with the "one" and "two" buttons? When the one button is pressed, transition to the next frame. I'm not sure how to work that.

[image]

This is the code for the first instance of our game (as seen in the picture):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class SampleWindow extends JFrame{
private JTextArea text;
private JButton one, two;

public SampleWindow(){
    super("0");

    Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    text =  new JTextArea("You are a female college student named Angelina Jackson \n"
            + "who is currently on a break from studying. \n"
            + "You are just at your favorite neighborhood cafe one day, \n" 
            + "when you bump into a stranger and spill your coffee all over both of you! \n" 
            + "What do you do?\n"
            + "Option one: Immediately apologize for being so clumsy. \n"
            + "Option two: You're furious because your shoes were brand new. \n"
            + "You turn around and prepare to give him the scolding of his life! \n");
    text.setFont(myFont);
    text.setEditable(false);

    one = new JButton("Option one: ");
    two = new JButton("Option two: ");

    panel.add(text);
    panel2.add(one);
    panel2.add(two);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER); 


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampleWindow sample = new SampleWindow();
    sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    sample.setSize(600, 350); //top by side
    sample.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And here is the code for the second instance:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class SampleWindow extends JFrame{
private JTextArea text;
private JButton one, two;

public SampleWindow(){
    super("0");

    Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    text =  new JTextArea("The guy is so angry, it's starting to be a little scary.\n"
            + "You decide that you'd better just get out of there quickly before someone gets hurt.\n"
            + "Where do you go next?\n"
            + "Option one: Go home and finish your math homework.\n"
            + "Option two: Go to the bank and get cash so that you can go shopping.\n"
            + "Please enter \"one\" for the first option, and \"two\" for the second option.");
    text.setFont(myFont);
    text.setFont(myFont);
    text.setEditable(false);

    one = new JButton("Option one: ");
    two = new JButton("Option two: ");

    panel.add(text);
    panel2.add(one);
    panel2.add(two);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER); 


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampleWindow sample = new SampleWindow();
    sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    sample.setSize(600, 350); //top by side
    sample.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

How would I link the frames together through the use of JButton? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use more than one frame? It would be easier to only have one window and replace the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I link the frames together through the use of JButton?

Don't swap JFrames as their no need and further the user interface would be much better served by simplifying. Instead the best solution is to create one JFrame that displays your JTextArea and simply change the text displayed in the JTextArea that it holds.

This would make your code a lot simpler and shorter, and would save the user the fatigue of seeing swapping windows, something that you rarely see in professional applications because it can be annoying to the user.

Myself, I'd put the text in a text file and not in the program, with the separate displayed strings separated perhaps by two empty lines, I'd have my program read in the lines into two (or more) Strings, and then on button push, swap the text in the JTextArea by calling `setText(...)` on it, passing in the new String.

For an example that uses a `HashMap<String, String>` to help swap text (but this is certainly not necessary).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwapText extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROWS = 25;
   private static final int COLS = 40;
   private static final String ABE_LINCOLN = "Abraham Lincoln's Gettysburg Address";
   private static final String CHIEF_JOSEPH = "Chief Joseph's Surrender Speech";
   private static final Font TXT_AREA_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18);
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
   private Map<String, String> optionTextMap = new HashMap<>();

   public SwapText() {
      // add text to Map
      optionTextMap.put(ABE_LINCOLN,
                  "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, "
                        + "upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and "
                        + "dedicated to the proposition that all men are created"
                        + " equal.\n\n"
                        +

                        "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether "
                        + "that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, "
                        + "can long endure. "
                        + "We are met here on a great battlefield of that war. "
                        + "We have come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who "
                        + "here gave their lives that that nation might live. "
                        + "It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.\n\n"
                        +

                        "But in a larger sense, we can not dedicate — we can not "
                        + "consecrate — we can not hallow — this ground. The brave men, living and dead, "
                        + "who struggled here, have consecrated it far above our "
                        + "poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember, "
                        + "what we say here, but can never forget what they did here.\n\n"
                        +

                        "It is for us, the living, rather to be dedicated here "
                        + "to the unfinished work which they have, thus far, so nobly carried on. It is "
                        + "rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task "
                        + "remaining before us — that from these honored dead we take increased devotion "
                        + "to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of "
                        + "devotion – that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in "
                        + "vain; that this nation shall have a new birth of freedom; "
                        + "and that this government of the people, by the people, for the people, "
                        + "shall not perish from the earth.");
      optionTextMap.put(CHIEF_JOSEPH,
                  "I am tired of fighting.  Our chiefs are killed.  Looking Glass is dead.  Toohulhulsote is dead.  "
                        + "The old men are all dead.  It is the young men who say yes or no. He who led the young men is dead.\n\n"
                        + "It is cold and we have no blankets.  The little children are freezing to death.  "
                        + "My people, some of them, have run away to the hills and have no blankets, "
                        + "no food.  No one knows where they are--perhaps freezing to death.  "
                        + "I want to have time to look for my children and see how many I can find.  "
                        + "Maybe I shall find them among the dead. \n\n"
                        + "Hear me, my chiefs.  I am tired.  My heart is sick and sad.  "
                        + "From where the sun now stands, I will fight no more forever.");

      // allow text area to wrap lines automatically
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      textArea.setFocusable(false); // so folks can't edit text
      textArea.setFont(TXT_AREA_FONT);

      // place text area in a JScrollPane
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new OptionAction(ABE_LINCOLN)));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new OptionAction(CHIEF_JOSEPH)));

      // use a BorderLayout for the main JPanel and add components
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class OptionAction extends AbstractAction {
      public OptionAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         textArea.setText(optionTextMap.get(getValue(NAME)));
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwapText mainPanel = new SwapText();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swap Text");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I'm still sort of new to programming, so how would you change the text displayed each time a button is pressed?

Comment: @Karen: simply call `setText(...)` on the JTextArea in your button's ActionListener. This is all well described in the appropriate [Swing Tutorial section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: Once I click the a button and the next text appears, how would I change the buttons to call different text? Because I go from the start to two options, and then the two options have two options within them each, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a model class that holds the text and two int indexes.

Next, create a List of model instances.  Point the two int indexes to the index in the ArrayList of the next model instance.

Finally, as others have said, create one JFrame with one JTextArea and two JButtons.  Update the values of these Swing components based on the values in the List of model instances.

Comment: Yes, model before view is the way to go. 1+